# Unable to Post to user's Facebook Timeline via "publish_actions" Permission

Tags: asp.net, facebook, facebook-login

I'm building a small website in asp.net which let the user login via facebook and then the app 
can post to user's timeline, i'm using scope="publish_actions,manage_pages" but when user login, app never asks the permission to post on the wall, it only gets the permission to access public profile, here is my code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.IO;
using Facebook;
namespace EadProject.Controllers
{
    public class LoginController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Login/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        public ActionResult FacebookLogin()
        {
            string app_id = "1415837275360274";
            string app_secret = "911b08ff5ae3cdaf74e512ce1c312c65";
            string scope = "publish_actions,manage_pages";
            if (Request["code"] == null)
            {
                Response.Redirect(string.Format("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id={0}&redirect_uri={1}&scope={2}",app_id,Request.Url.AbsoluteUri,scope));

            }
            else
            {
                Dictionary<string, string> tokens = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                string url = string.Format("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id={0}&redirect_uri={1}&scope={2}&code={3}&client_secret={4}", app_id, Request.Url.AbsoluteUri, scope,Request["code"].ToString(),app_secret);
                HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
                using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
                {
                    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
                    string vals = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    foreach (string token in vals.Split('&'))
                    {
                        tokens.Add(token.Substring(0,token.IndexOf("=")),token.Substring(token.IndexOf("=")+1,token.Length-token.IndexOf("=")-1));


                    }
                }
                string access_token = tokens["access_token"];
                var client = new FacebookClient(access_token);
                client.Post("/me/feed", new { message = "I am using QUiz Contest Pucit App developed by AHmed ALI :)" });
                StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(new FileStream("C:\tokens.txt",FileMode.OpenOrCreate));
                sw.WriteLine(access_token);


            }
            return View();
        }

    }
}
```

Please explain what is the problem?

Comment: Beacause it doen't ask for permission for posting, the code gives an exception at the following line client.Post("/me/feed", new { message = "I am using QUiz Contest Pucit App developed by AHmed ALI :)" });

Comment: (OAuthException - #200) (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action

Comment: I am having the same problem. I'm sending scope=publish_actions too  but the dialogue does not ask for publish permission. As far as I can understand it should open a second dialogue that asks for the publish permission...?